# SELECT using psql returns no rows even though data is there

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using Django + Postgres. When I do a SQL query using psql, 
e.g. \d+ myapp_stories
correctly shows the columns in the table

But when I do SELECT * FROM myapp_stories, it returns nothing. But querying the same database & table from my python code returns data just fine. So there is data in the table. Any thoughts? I'm using venv, not sure if that affects anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to enter semicolon:

> SELECT * FROM myapp_stories;

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the table in your query with the schema, as the `search_path` might be causing your query (or psql) to look in a schema other than what you are expecting.